# How to exclude specific text in perl regexp match

Tags: regex, perl

I am using perl to parse a large report file.  I pull out names by looking for last name and first name at the beginning of some lines of the report.  I am trying to exclude text following the name.  Some of these text fields are numbers, thus easy -- I just look for non-digit characters.  But some are fixed text fields that I can list.

E.g. ---

```
LastNameA, FirstNameA
LastNameB, FirstNameB 345C
LastNameC, FirstNameC BADTEXT
LastNameD, FirstNameD MOREBADTEXT
```

I have tried the following

```
/^(\D*)((BADTEXT|MOREBADTEXT|))/
/^(\D*)(BADTEXT|MOREBADTEXT|)/
/^(\D*?)((BADTEXT|MOREBADTEXT|))/
/^(\D*)((BADTEXT|MOREBADTEXT)?)/
/^(\D*)(?:(BADTEXT|MOREBADTEXT|))/
```

and several other combinations.  But I get either no match or a match with BADTEXT or MOREBADTEXT sucked into $1 instead of $2.  I either want the bad text in $2 or not matched at all.

Note that the text I don't want appended to the name will be one of a very small list of known text strings, so I can add them to the conditional group.

I have read through perlretut twice but can't find how to do this.   Seems like it should be simple!  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just ignore the extra text you dont want in your regex: `/(\w+), (\w+)/`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this doesn't work because the name field sometimes has middle initial, JR, SR, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting the text on whitespace and only keeping the parts you like?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line=<DATA>) {
    my @name=grep { ! /\d|^BADTEXT$|^MOREBADTEXT$/ } split /\s+/, $line;
    print "@name\n";
}

__DATA__
LastNameA, FirstNameA
LastNameB, FirstNameB 345C
LastNameC, FirstNameC BADTEXT
LastNameD, FirstNameD MOREBADTEXT
```

Result:

```
LastNameA, FirstNameA
LastNameB, FirstNameB
LastNameC, FirstNameC
LastNameD, FirstNameD
```

This of course means that you need to know that no names have digits in them (no Wainright 3, Loudon), and that you can create an exhaustive list of texts you want excluded, and that those never are equal to words in names.

If you know that there is exactly one lastname and one firstname, you can just grab the first two elements that split() returns.

Comment: That will work.  I was stubbornly looking for a solution that embedded everything into one regexp.  But sometimes it's better to keep it simple and move on!  Thanks.

Comment: It is common to want regexes to do everything. Sometimes that just makes it more complicated.